# Creating a tile dashboard using angular js

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-directive, dashboard

I am creating a dashboard application in Angular JS, which will have different tiles. Each tile has its own specific data & HTML.

Thought of approaching the problem with

```
<div ng-repeat="tile in tiles">
<dashboard-tile/>
</div>
```

where  is a directive. But i have following doubts-
1. Since each tile will have different HTML(content), how can i repeat it through a single directive template.
2. If i want to inherit from a base tile and add own properties (model+content) to the tile, how can i then repeat the tile in HTML.

Not sure how to proceed or design the solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
Sonny

Comment: If these tiles are specific to the dashboard, and are not meant to replicated widgets, I wouldn't be concerned about making them inherit from a shared directive. You aren't really buying yourself anything if they all have unique html, css and js associated with them. They can (and should) be directives, just don't force it into an inherited relationship.

If there are shared properties, can you elaborate on them?

Comment: so what do you suggest, make them individual directives and include in the HTML rather than use ng-repeat? But what if there are a lot of unique tiles.

Comment: What are you even repeating against? `ng-repeat` is normally used to repeat an array of items of the same type. You have a bunch of disparate widgets seemingly. What are their unifying properties? Would you expect them to use the same data source & structure? Also, is the presence of the widget data driven? Is it always there, or only based on certain data points?

Comment: Okay, got your point. Is there any way to dynamically load a directive based on a condition. Like-
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <widget widgetId="item.widgetId">
          <div widget-id></div>
     </widget>
</div>

where everytime based on condition the directive is different.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're looking for, I'd say you'd want to `ng-repeat` with a `ng-switch`, and then list out the possible widgets with `ng-switch-when`.

```
            <div class="widget"  ng-repeat="item in items" ng-switch="item.type">

                <widget-activity-feed ng-switch-when="activity" >
                </widget-activity-feed>
                <widget-monthly-income ng-switch-when="income">
                </widget-monthly-income>

            </div>
```

Comment: Hey Dylan, i think i found the way. But i'm facing one more issue for DOM manipulation. I was using the jquery UI drag and drop logic for the tiles initially. Now i want to write the same DOM logic somewhere in the parent directive, which will be applicable to all child directives instead of copy pasting in all the child directives. But iam unable to determine where to write that in the parent directive. Is there a place in the parent directive which says now the directive DOM is ready, place your logic here. something like jquery ready